# InternetGetConnectedState and "it should not be used from a service" statement from MSDN

Tags: c++, winapi, service, windows-services

I'm programming a Windows local service using C++ and WinAPIs. From within that service I need to know that an Internet connection is available (in general) so I came up with the [`InternetGetConnectedState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API but then after reading the MSDN I found this in the Remarks section:

> In addition, it should not be used from a service.

Well, "thank you", Microsoft!

Does anyone have any idea why and what alternative can I use from a service.

PS. I don't want to use the ping approach because obviously there's no way of knowing that the site I'm pinging is up, so it then opens up a whole new can of worms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't need to care whether the Internet is available, you just attempt to make the connection to the site and deal with any failure.

Comment: I know. In my case it'll save a lot of CPU cycles if I know that the Internet connection is on up front. Again, the point of this question is why this API is "bad" for a service and what is the alternative?

Comment: The API is "bad" for a service because it's the one that prompts to dial-up the Internet or work offline.

Comment: OK. That makes sense. Do you know of any alternatives?

Comment: Try and connect and handle failure. Any other method will cause a race condition, as the state may change between your check and trying to use it.

Comment: Yes, I understand it, but it's not that simple. Here's a quick example. In my service, if I know that the Internet connection is not available I can reschedule to retry in a short while (in 30 seconds, for instance) but if the error came from the web server itself not being able to process the request I'd reschedule a retry after a longer pause (10 minutes, for instance.) So how do you handle this with your approach? It brings a whole new can of worms to deal with (socket errors, etc.)

Comment: Presumably the server will fail with an HTTP status of 500, which is readily distinguishable from a connection failure.

Comment: OK. I admit, there's no easy way of doing it... not that I know at this point... so I'll stick with your answer.