# How to check whether an internet connection is available without prompting the dial-up dialog?

Tags: .net, http, dial-up

I'd like my application to connect to a server (to check for updates) whenever a connection is available, but do nothing when it isn't. I'm worried that people with a dial-up connection might receive one of those prompts to dial their ISP whenever my program attempts this. I realise very few people are on dial-up nowadays, but still.

I myself have been off dial-up for more than a decade, so I honestly have no idea whether performing an HTTP request (e.g. using a `WebRequest`) while offline will show such a "dial" prompt. Will it? If so, how can I check for updates without causing such a prompt?

Comment: people with a dial-up connection? If they don't buy a real internet connection, what makes you think they will buy your software?

Comment: @HighCore Do yourself a favor and stop writing code.  Tons of people live in rural areas that go to cyber cafes / starbucks / whatever to download software/ buy a CD/DVD with software on it.

Comment: Why the concern over the dial up prompt?

Comment: @Woot4Moo Because it's annoying, and I'd hate to be annoying to our users. And because I have a vague memory of that dial-up prompt popping up automatically. I may have also seen a blog post about this recently, but I couldn't find an answer by googling.

Comment: What I meant was why the concern (assuming) you haven't been able to test it.  Or is this from prior experience?

Comment: @Woot4Moo This is from very vague memories from a very long time ago :) Plus, someone mentioning that a call to `InternetCheckConnection` does that.

Comment: @romkyns Are you saying your belief is that `InternetCheckConnection` will cause the dialog you are trying to avoid?

Comment: @LJVanKuiken Hm, maybe it was `InternetGetConnectedState`. Finally found where I saw this: [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320366/internetgetconnectedstate-and-it-should-not-be-used-from-a-service-statement-f#comment14901430_11320572).

Answer (score 1):

By using this:

```
My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable
```

And maybe this:

```
    Dim available As Boolean
    Try
        Dim client As New System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient("google.com", 80)
        available = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        available = False
    End Try
```

If the result is "available", you may check for whether the update is available or not.

Comment: Do you have proof that this will not cause the dial-up dialog to pop up?

Comment: In your case, I would certainly use the first one. Since it has nothing to do with attempting to make a connection, I can say I am 95% sure. Yet I have no evidence :(

Comment: LJVanKuiken suggests that `IsAvailable` calls `InternetGetConnectedState` under the hood, and there is at least one [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320366/internetgetconnectedstate-and-it-should-not-be-used-from-a-service-statement-f#comment14901430_11320572) that suggests this call will cause the dial-up prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The [WinInet Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implements the function:

```
BOOL InternetGetConnectedState(
  _Out_  LPDWORD lpdwFlags,
  _In_   DWORD dwReserved
);
```

Details of the specfic API call can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

**EDIT:** 
I've provided a small code sample that could be used for testing.
It is worth noting that under the hood, `My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable` P/Invokes `InternetGetConnectedState` and simply returns a **true/false** value while discarding the flags.  WinNt and later it enumerates through the network interfaces and returns true for the first connected interface.

```
using System;

namespace InternetGetConnectedState
{
    [Flags]
    enum InternetConnectionFlags : uint
    {
        // Flags for InternetGetConnectedState and Ex
        Modem = 0x01,
        Lan = 0x02,
        Proxy = 0x04,
        ModemBusy = 0x08,  /* no longer used */
        RasInstalled = 0x10,
        Offline = 0x20,
        Configured = 0x40
    }

    class Program
    {
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool InternetGetConnectedState(out InternetConnectionFlags flags, uint dwReserved);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            InternetConnectionFlags flags;
            bool connectedState = InternetGetConnectedState(out flags, 0)

            // TODO:  Check Flags
        }
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 2:**
After further reviewing an ILSpy dump, `My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable` P/Invokes `InternetGetConnectedState` on Windows prior to NT.  On WinNt and later, it enumerates through the network interfaces and returns true for the first connected interface.  So, either

```
My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable  'vb.net
```

or

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.GetIsNetworkAvailable(); // C#
```

are viable solutions.

Perhaps an option to disable automatic updates is another possible solution to avoid end user annoyance.

Comment: There is at least one [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320366/internetgetconnectedstate-and-it-should-not-be-used-from-a-service-statement-f#comment14901430_11320572) that suggests this call **will** cause the dial-up prompt.

Comment: @romkyns  There is nothing to substantiate this assertion.  Microsoft does not support services implementing the WinInet API because there are *portions* of the Api that require user interaction and service implementations prohibit that.